# Как вызвать метод класса для экземпляра имя которого получено с input()

Tags: python, классы

```
class Robot:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print(f'Рообот {self.name} создан')

    def jump(self):
        print(f'Робот {self.name} подпрыгнул')

robot1 = Robot('R2-D2')
robot2 = Robot('C-3PO')

jumper = input('Какой робот должен подпрыгнуть?')
jumper.jump()
```

Если ввести "robot1" должно вывестись "Робот R2-D2 подпрыгнул".
Но возвращается ошибка: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'jump'.

Наверное глупый вопрос: какого типа данных название атрибута класса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [15]: class Robot:
    ...:
    ...:     def __init__(self, name):
    ...:         self.name = name
    ...:         print(f'Рообот {self.name} создан')
    ...:
    ...:     def jump(self):
    ...:         print(f'Робот {self.name} подпрыгнул')
    ...:

In [16]: class RobotRegistry:
    ...:     robots = {}
    ...:
    ...:     @classmethod
    ...:     def register(cls, robot):
    ...:         cls.robots[robot.name] = robot
    ...:

In [17]: robot1 = Robot('R2-D2')
Рообот R2-D2 создан

In [18]: robot2 = Robot('C-3PO')
Рообот C-3PO создан

In [19]: RobotRegistry.register(robot1)

In [20]: RobotRegistry.register(robot2)

In [21]: robot_name = input("Enter robot name: ")
Enter robot name: R2-D2

In [22]: RobotRegistry.robots[robot_name].jump()
Робот R2-D2 подпрыгнул
```

Можно определить какие-то вспомогательные методы у `RobotRegistry`, чтобы явно не ходить в `.robots`.

По поводу подпрыгивания робота по имени переменной:

```
In [31]: locals()[input()].jump()
robot1
Робот R2-D2 подпрыгнул
```

Но так делать не рекомендуется.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Robot:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print(f'Робот {self.name} создан')

    def jump(self):
        print(f'Робот {self.name} подпрыгнул')

robot1 = Robot('R2-D2')
robot2 = Robot('C-3PO')

jumper = input('Какой робот должен подпрыгнуть?: ')

if jumper.lower() == 'r2-d2':
    robot1.jump()
if jumper.lower() == 'c-3po':
    robot2.jump()
else:
    print('Error')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if jumper == str(robot1.name):
robot1.jump()
elif jumper == str(robot2.name):
robot2.jump()
else:
print("Такого робота нет")
```

Answer (score -2):

Почему бы не передать эту строку в конструктор робота? Не надо никаких проверок тогда, самое очевидное решение:

```
class Robot:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print(f'Рообот {self.name} создан')

    def jump(self):
        print(f'Робот {self.name} подпрыгнул')

jumper = Robot(input('Какой робот должен подпрыгнуть?'))
jumper.jump()
```

Если вам нужна какая-то валидация для типа робота, то это должно происходить в объекте, а не вне его, сейчас вы принимаете произвольную строку.

Comment: Смысл тогда от классов? У него может быть много роботов с разными параметрами, у вас же робот один и его имя всегда меняется.

Comment: @PavelDurmanov не понял вопроса, таким же способом можно создать N роботов, не только одного. У ТС в коде только 1 прыгает, как и тут

Comment: Ваш робот не имеет никаких уникальных параметров. Если я захочу 2 робота с разным весом например, ваш код мне не поможет.

Comment: О каких параметрах речь? В вопросе про вес ничего не было

Comment: В вопросе минимальный шаблон, если человек использует классы, значит экземпляры этого класс будут отличатся.

Comment: Не понимаю, к чему вы ведёте. В этот код можно добавить аттрибут `self.weight` и передавать этот вес вторым параметром конструктора. Тогда роботы, созданные с разным весом, будут отличаться

Comment: Да, но в вашем коде экземпляр робота делается на лету основываясь на имени переданном  в инпуте.

Comment: При создании робота мне придется отвечать на вопрос "Какой робот должен подпрыгнуть?" даже если я не собираюсь его заставлять прыгать. Как правильно заметил @PavelDurmanov - "В вопросе минимальный шаблон".

Comment: @DimaZahaiko если вам нужна валидация "прыгающий ли данный робот", то надо делать это в самом классе, а не вне его. Самый очевидный вариант — наследование. А в текущем виде — определение по названию — вариант, который я привёл, считаю самым простым

Comment: Прыгает робот или нет зависит от внешних факторов, не от внутренних, о какой валидации внутри класса идет речь?

Comment: @PavelDurmanov есть 2 принципиально разные ситуации: 1) любой робот может прыгать => мы просто передаём название робота, который сейчас прыгнет и конструируем его на месте, потому что зачем конструировать роботов, которые ничего не делают? 2) существуют прыгающие и не прыгающие роботы, в таком случае используем наследование и опять не нужны никакие проверки, вызываем `jump` только у прыгающих

Comment: Прыгает робот или нет зависит от ВНЕШНИХ факторов, юзер хочет чтобы прыгнул робот А а не Б, наследование тут не поможет.

Comment: @PavelDurmanov если он хочет, чтобы из списка роботов прыгали только прыгающие, то поможет. Если он хочет чтобы конкретный прыгающий из уже существующих прыгающих прыгнул, то тогда подойдут другие ответы

Comment: В вопросе буквально 2 прыгающих робота и прыгнуть должен только один.

Comment: @PavelDurmanov ну а я предложил решение с 1 прыгающим роботом, без лишнего второго :)